# Get content of single by slug

Tags: entries, slug, singles, templating

I'm trying to get the content of a single using a slug from the url.
I'm using the following code:

```
{% set item = craft.entries.slug(craft.request.getSegment(1)).first() %}
```

This doesn't work, returns null, if there is a dash in segment 1.

For example if I have the following url: http://craft.dev/this-is-a-segment/segment2 
And in craftcms I have a single with title "This is a segment" and url "this-is-a-segment"
I can't get the content of that single.

If I change the slug to camelcase it does work, but I was under the impression that slug and section handle were two different things...

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: your code above should work provided your slug is the same as the first segment. have you double checked? if yes, and you're on the latest version of craft, then i would report it as a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singles have no need for slugs, which is why we don't expose them in the CP UI for a single.

They only have one in the database because they're technically entries, and entries need slugs. But it's only a concept meant for Channel and Structure entries.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that either the single's uri or the handle is technically considered a slug per se, although in the case of singles craft likely interprets the handle as such. A more appropriate way to access a single would be by using its section handle.

(updated)

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment(1) == "this-is-a-segment" %}
    {% set item = craft.entries.section('mySectionHandle').first() %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Your code won't work. In my example the slug returned from getSegment(1) is "this-is-a-segment". The section name however is thisIsASegment

Comment: ah... your right, of course it did. If you want to do this I would suggest making sure that the uri that you are using also matches the single's handle. Either that or use a conditional to use the correct handle.

Comment: That's what the craft.entries.section() function is for. I expected the craft.entries.slug() funtion to behave differently, which it does when using it to get the content of a channel or structure entry.